# split FULL_NAME into LAST,FIRST & MIDDLE NAME

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How to split names(LAST_NAME,FIRST_NAME & MIDDLE_NAME) from a FULL_NAME column of the following format:

```
FULL_NAME: BARN,KE ROMAN where FIRST_NAME: KE, MIDDLE_NAME: ROMAN & LAST_NAME: BARN
```

I was able to write the below sql but, how do I add the MIDDLE_NAME query and also what if the MIDDLE_NAME is null (ex-- FULL_NAME: BARN,KE)

```
SELECT TRIM (SUBSTR (NAMES, INSTR (NAMES, ',', 1) + 1)) AS FIRST_NAME,
       TRIM (SUBSTR (NAMES, 1, INSTR (NAMES, ',', 1) - 1)) AS LAST_NAME
FROM TABLE
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: This is something of an ugly problem, because a) not everyone has a middle name, and b) some people may have more than three words in their name (e.g. Jean Claude Van Damn).

Comment: This is solvable only for a very regular data set of names.  People with hyphens in their names like  Bob Langdon-Jones or Jean-Paul So-and-So make it a better idea to have your table as First_name, Last_Name and even then...

Comment: Actually I want to make it as this code

Comment: What would you want returned for the string "Cave, Justin Owen Jennings" or "Smith, Mary Beth Ann".  In one case, the person has two middle names.  In the other, the person has a space in their first name.  Once you pick which name you want to parse incorrectly, you can pick an implementation.

Comment: Okay then what if I have all the 3 different fields and want to write in one field like FIRST_NAME|| MIDDLE_NAME|| LAST_NAME but with the space. Now if the middle name is null then the above works or else there will not be any space. How do I handle this?\

Comment: FIRST_NAME || case when MIDDLE_NAME is not null then ' ' || MIDDLE_NAME end || ' ' || LAST_NAME

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Substr(fullname, 1, Instr(fullname, ' ') - 1) AS First_Name, 
       Substr(fullname, Instr(fullname, ' ') + 1)    AS Last_Name 
FROM   emp; 

SELECT Substr('Amit Chauhan', 1, Instr('Amit Chauhan', ' ') - 1) AS First_Name, 
       Substr('Amit Chauhan', Instr('Amit Chauhan', ' ') + 1)    AS Last_Name 
FROM   dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `regexp_substr()` is your best bet here:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('BARN,KE ROMAN', '[^ ]*$')
```

This anchors to the end of the string `$` then sort of looks forward until it hits the space. That `[^ ]` bit is like saying "Every character that isn't a space".

Like others have pointed out, this is a crap shoot if you have a middle name with a space in it. You'll just have to hope to be close if you have names that don't match `first,last middle` format.

Comment: If you concatenate your names like that you will end up with JOHNBOBSMITH and there is no way to undo that. Also, you should ask this as a new question.

Comment: @JustinCave
In your question with 'Cave, Justin Owen Jennings' & 'Smith, Mary Beth Ann'.... What would be the answer?

Thanks!